# Python - manipulating pyodbc.fetchall() into a pandas usable format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pyodbc

I'm writing a program that obtains data from a database using pyodbc, the end goal being to analyze this data with a pandas.

as it stands, my program works quite well to connect to the database and collect the data that I need, however I'm having some trouble organizing or formatting this data in such a way that I can analyze it with pandas, or simply write it out clean to a .csv file (I know I can do this with pandas as well).

Here is the basis of my simple program:

```
from Logger import Logger
import pyodbc
from configparser import ConfigParser
from connectDB import connectDatabase, disconnectDatabase

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
getNeedlesPlaintiffs = config.get('QUERIES', 'pullNeedlesPlaintiffs')
getNeedlesDefendants = config.get('QUERIES', 'pullNeedlesDefendants')

def pullNeedlesData():
    Logger.writeAndPrintLine("Connecting to needles db...", 0)
    cnxn = connectDatabase()
    if cnxn:
        cursor=cnxn.cursor()
        Logger.writeAndPrintLine("Connection successful. Getting Plaintiffs...", 0)
        cursor.execute(getNeedlesPlaintiffs)
        with open('needlesPlaintiffs.csv', 'w') as f:
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                row = str(row)
                f.write(row)
        f.close()

        Logger.writeAndPrintLine("Plaintiffs written to file, getting Defendants...", 0)
        cursor.execute(getNeedlesDefendants)
        with open('needlesDefendants.csv', 'w') as d:
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                row = str(row)
                d.write(row)
        d.close()
        disconnectDatabase(cnxn)
        Logger.writeAndPrintLine("Defendants obtained, written to file.", 0)
    else:
        Logger.writeAndPrintLine("Connection to Needles DB Failed.", 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pullNeedlesData()
```

However, the output I'm getting in the .csv (and console) is simply unworkable. I would like to parse my data into a list of dictionaries, so that I can more easily use it for analysis with pandas.

For example, something like this (which I can then json.loads() into a pandas dataframe):

```
    text_data = '[{"lname": "jones", "fname": "matt", "dob": "01-02-1990", "addr1": "28 sheffield dr"},\
    {"lname": "kalinski", "fname": "fred", "dob": "01-02-1980", "addr1": "28 purple st"}, \
         {"lname": "kyle", "fname": "ken", "dob": "05-01-1978", "addr1": "28 carlisle dr"}, \
             {"lname": "jones", "fname": "matt", "dob": "01-02-1990", "addr1": "new address"}, \
                 {"lname": "kalinski", "fname": "fred", "dob": "01-02-1980", "addr1": "28 purple st"}, \
                     {"lname": "kyle", "fname": "ken", "dob": "05-01-1979", "addr1": "other address"}]'
```

Where I am now, I'm simply at a loss for how one would go about parsing this data from pyodbc.fetchall() into what I know I can work with- a list of dictionaries. Additionally, I would eventually like to print results to csv in a readable way.

My data is currently returned in a format like this:

```
(238384, 'Mr. Nathan Brown', 'Person', datetime.date(1989, 2, 3), '41 Fake Rd 1 \r\nTownName, State 13827')(283928, 'Mr. Logan Green', 'Person', datetime.date(2003, 5, 18), '36 county rd \r\nTownName, State 14432')(38272, 'Mrs. Penellope Blue', 'Person', datetime.date(1988, 1, 27), '123 fake st \r\nTownName, State, 14280)(...)
```

I realize I need to create an empty list object, then parse each row into a dictionary, and add it to the list- but I've never had to work with data on this scale and I'm wondering if there's a library or something that makes this type of work easier to accomplish.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just import the data directly into pandas ?
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, db.connection)

Comment: That would definitely eliminate a lot of the work I'm creating for myself here..... did not know pandas could read directly from db. Thank you for the insight- looking into the correct syntax to implement.